# Keep frying constant-current LED drivers and LED PCB modules

Tags: arduino, led, led-driver, constant-current

This has happened twice and I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong so that I don't fry another set of drivers and LEDs.

I have an array of high-intensity LEDs for a crop imaging application looking for plant fluorescence.

We have strips of copper PCBs that were custom made with chains of six green and blue high-intensity LEDs on them (in the application we alternate looking at the plants under green and blue light).

[image: The array]

To drive these boards, I am using Mean Well constant current drivers on a custom PCB I made which powers four drivers at a time and routes control signal to two at a time.

This lets me control these ten LED strips from five boards, turning on the blue and green channels as needed.

[image]

(Yes, it's ugly... I'm going to eventually have wires cut to length, and have a metal backplate and wire troughs... I just use wood backplates for the first version because I almost always change something...)

For each carrier board, I can control two of the drivers at a time individually. The drivers are [Mean-Well NLDD-1400H](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/NLDD-H/NLDD-H-spec.pdf). Each driver board has an individual connection to a DIN rail distribution block... I'm not daisy-chaining the power.

The drivers are always on if not connected, so I have them wired to the Arduino and added 18k pull-down resistors for each channel.

I am only using two outputs, one for each color and am daisy-chaining the signal to each of the control boards, splitting the one in the middle.

The simplified wiring layout I made in Lucidchart [here](https://lucid.app/lucidchart/8140308c-0154-452a-ad33-0421c4683167/edit?viewport_loc=-2930%2C-2223%2C7221%2C3569%2C0_0&invitationId=inv_6be48bf8-520b-42f6-a6de-24528048cc71).

In any case, what has happened ***twice*** now, is that I have fried the last set of drivers on the green channel. Sizzling bacon sound, hole appeared in the driver... the smoke got out... very, very dead.

When that happened, it also killed the green side of my LEDs.

The blue channel has never had a problem... and from what I can tell, it is wired exactly the same way.

I don't know when they died the first time, but after replacing them, I applied power and attempted to turn the lights on manually (not through the Arduino, but manually touching the control wire for the greens to ground and 3.3 V to try to get them to turn on).

I don't know if maybe it didn't like brief contact on the control signal because these are also PWM drivers... and a quick intermittent contact did something? But the frying sound happened pretty quickly.

Both times it was the last set of drivers at the very end of the daisy-chained string of driver boards. I don't think that is a coincidence. When they fried the second time, it was a new set of LEDs and a fresh set of drivers on a new carrier board...

Trying an image of my wiring diagram here:

[image]

I'm wondering if the daisy-chaining is killing the green drivers?  Or maybe me providing a brief control signal... or maybe I have something wired wrong...

Comment: Can you put a wiring diagram in your post as well as a link to the driver datasheet? It is hard to understand what you're doing from just that picture.

Comment: I posted a simplified wiring diagram in that lucidchart link.   I tried exporting it as a jpeg just now and found an option for makingi it large enough to be legible...   please see the post again for that image... thank you!

Comment: What is the total voltage of your 18S lithium battery when fully charged?  Does it exceed the maximum input voltage of the drivers when fully charged?  I think it would unless the cell voltage is very low.

Comment: Something has to different between the blue and green systems, even though they appear to be the same.  Do you have the datasheets for the blue and green LEDs?  Also: It appears you also have white strips of LEDs (perhaps white LEDs?) ... how are they connected?

Comment: Do you ever need to use the blue and the green LEDs at the same time?

Comment: I'm going to ask what user1850479 already did, because it's important: what input voltage are you applying to the driver modules? An 18S LiFePO4 battery would be over 60V fully charged, and those drivers are rated for only 56V in normal operation.

Comment: answering some questions:  The battery fully charged is at 53v.  So I felt the 56v rating of the drivers was fine.

re the Green LED's.. they were picked by a co-worker who recently left the company, so I dont have the LED Specs yet, i have written to the supplier for that info.

re: blue and green...  we have had both channels on at the same time during setup and testing, but in operation, that will never happen, we are looking for flourescence exccited by either green or blue light, and there is a filter on the camera behind this array which changes when you switch the LED color

Comment: .... But even when we first fired up the array, the last 4 green LED's were not working...  We replaced the drivers, still not working, tested the LED's with new drivers... those werent working, replaced the LED's and used a fresh set of drivers, and they melted down almost immediatley...

Comment: Correction:  My battery is 16s LiFEPO4... not 18...  Still 53v is close to the 56v limit for those drivers... so since so many people are asking that question, Im considering adding a 48v DC/DC power converter to the battery to tone down the voltage these drivers are seeing just a bit...

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, I'd check the peak battery voltage.

Depending on charge state, one cell could be as high as 3.4V.  18 of them gives 61.2V.  (I am assuming you're not charging at the same time as using, because then the voltage would be much higher?)

The PSU datasheet states Vin as 10V-56V, with 59V as the absolute maximum.

61.2V > 59V & 61.2V >> 56V.

You should also consider twisting the two PSU wires for each driver, as large loop areas with increase the inductance, and may lead to voltage surges during switching transients, which given that you are already marginal/exceeding Vin could add to your problems.

As for why green is failing as blue isn't, the per LED operating voltage is higher for blue than green (bigger bandgap), potentially making it more tolerant of overvoltage and/or requiring less voltage drop in the controller.  I know you have current control on the LED strings, but have you checked the maximum voltage of the two strings?  If this is significantly less than the LED driver maximum output (Vin-4V) you might have problems under transitory conditions and/or when the driver fails.

Comment: You might also want to verify the negative lines on the green and blue strings aren't interconnected, as that could cause some fun problems depending on the driver internals.

Comment: The negative lines ARE interconnected... everything here has a common ground leading back to some DIN terminal blocks, even the 12v arduino has a seperate ground wire to the same block so that I have a common ground.    Is that a bad thing?  I thought it was a necessary thing...

Comment: Connected on the PSU side is fine. I meant additional interconnect on output side.  This could cause a variety of issues depending on the internal psi design.